# File upload: How to exclude a MIME type using asserts?

Tags: symfony, mime-types, assert

In Symfony I can accept MIME types using:

```php
/**
  * @Assert\File( maxSize="10M", mimeTypes={"application/pdf", "image/png"} )
  */
public $file;
```

But how can I exclude something from that list? Let's say, I want to allow all uploads except for PHP files?

Comment: I'm afraid that you need to create your own constraint...

Comment: Hm, that's what I figured. Many thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: You should **always** whitelist rather than blacklist, just list the mimeTypes that you allow rather than don't allow

Comment: @Jaitsu, you are totally correct. but sometimes you need to upload any type of files except the most dangerous. For example, if you are creating file-manager for administator

Comment: @Pleerock I would still argue that you should whitelist, it might take longer to compile a whitelist than a blacklist but you'll end up with a more secure product

Comment: @Jaitsu, how would you create online ftp-manager? or something like CPanel file manager has. When admin want to upload on his own files of unknown extension. Is there only white list in Google Drive?

Comment: @Pleerock I'm sure you can find a whitelist of "safe" file types online somewhere, but use at your own caution. I would use a callback validator like lifo suggested and validate the mime type against a whitelist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could implement a [Callback constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/constraints/Callback.html) via an assert. One advantage of this method is you can apply the error message to any field (or fields) in your form.

```php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"validateFile"})
 */
class MyEntity
{

    public function validateFile(ExecutionContext $context)
    {
        $path = $context->getPropertyPath();
        if (/* $this->file is not in allowed mimeTypes ... */) {
            $context->setPropertyPath($path . '.file');
            $context->addViolation("Invalid file mimetype", array(), null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to create any callback to do this. Just make sure:

1) Set enable_annotations parameter as true in your app/config/config.yml:

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
```

2) Include properly the validation constraints on your entity file.

```
// YourEntity.php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
```

3) Use the annotation properly. Example:

```
// YourEntity.php
/**
 * @Assert\File(
 *      maxSize="5242880",
 *      mimeTypes = {
 *          "image/png",
 *          "image/jpeg",
 *          "image/jpg",
 *          "image/gif",
 *          "application/pdf",
 *          "application/x-pdf"
 *      }
 * )
 */
 private $arquivo;
```

The above code is working fine on my Symfony  2.3.9.

[]s

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. OP needs to Accept *any* mimeTypes **BUT** some.

Comment: You are right! Sorry, I was in another question too and answered the wrong one. My bad! =)

Comment: This is not the answer to the question.